# How to echo automatically all column values

Tags: php

For example I have an `attributes table` and I can add infinite attributes. I do that with `ALTER TABLE` when I add a new column and `UPDATE` when I insert the value of the attribute. All these columns must be shown in a table. However I am having dificulties with showing the newly added column value.

Here is how a static column value echo would look like:

```
public function showAllUsers(){
    $x = $this->getAllUsers();
    foreach ($x as $data) {
      echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>'. $data['id'].'</th>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['user'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['age'].'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  }
```

It echoes the values of the database that I have specified. But I need a loop that will echo any newly added value so the static echo method above won't work.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
public function showAllUsers(){
    $x = $this->getAllUsers();
    foreach ($x as $data) {

      echo '<tr>';
        print_r( '<th>'. $data.'</th>');
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  }
```

And it just shows a `Notice: Array to string conversion` and echoes one  tag with value of 0. How do i echo all of the content from one row?

Comment: Mobile here so don't judge my formatting. Do the loop with foreach ($x as $k=>$v) and echo both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function showAllUsers()
{
    $x = $this->getAllUsers();
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach (array_keys($x[0]) as $field) {
        echo '<th>'. $field.'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($x as $data) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($data as $val) {
            echo '<td>'. $val.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, add some description how it solves the problem. It helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can implode the $data array with the html tags.
Implode takes all array values and joins them with the "glue" and makes it a string.

```
public function showAllUsers(){
    $x = $this->getAllUsers();
    foreach($x as $data){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" . implode("</th><th>", $data) . "</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: still says Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: Yes sorry about that. You still need the foreach to loop the data. I will edit the answer

Comment: yeah i noticed it myself but thanks anyway this was what I was looking for, however I have two JOINED tables and now it echoes from both tables but i needed from one. Is there a way that I can limit to only that one?

Comment: How should I know? You have not included anything in your question about joined tables, what values to output or what the array looks like. You get answers based on what effort you put in to your question. If you do not include all necessary facts in your question then don't think we can read your mind and solve it for you.

Comment: okay, okay. I am just making this as I go first time doing this. I will find the answer myself. ty

Comment: You can just update your question with the edit button. But always include all necessary facts when you post the question. Most likely it's very simple to split the data.